# Regarding Dictionary Attack

Tags: attacks, dictionary

Since most websites will let user retry their password, lets say 3 times in a row, in case of mistype or forgotten password.
Exceeding the set number of retry the account will be locked or timed out.
If one were to use online dictionary attack to gain access to a certain account, wouldn't that be a very inefficient method? Why would one even want to use dictionary attack? or, perhaps this is my misunderstanding of how dictionary attack is carried out?

Answer (score 4):

A dictionary attack is usually carried out *offline*, not against an online website, for exactly the reason you raise.  It requires that the password database be compromised and available for offline attacks.

A [password spray attack](https://www.google.com/search?q=password%20spray%20attack) is more common for online resources.  With a password spray, a small number of passwords are tested against a large number of accounts, spreading out the attempts to avoid triggering locked accounts.  This is based on the fact that most accounts lock on X amount of failures *within a certain time frame*.

Even with a gentle password spray, locking out accounts is a real danger.  Online password attacks are hard!

Comment: I don't completely agree. Dictionary attacks are carried out online as well, just not against services that implement account lockout. E.g Attacking SSH service using Hydra + dictionary file.

Answer (score 2):

You raised some valid points:

1. **Dictionary attacks are inefficient** - Correct, yet they are used for a reason. Remember, the most basic attack is a *[shear Brute-Force attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack)*, where the attacker has no knowledge of the credentials in use.
   Dictionary attacks are therefore more efficient as the attacker have some knowledge of the credentials in use (e.g. password min/max length and complexity, top 100 passwords, etc.) therefore reducing the spread of the credentials to be tested - that's our dictionary.
2. **Account lockout can mitigate Dictionary attacks** - Yet you do need to remember - locking the account might mitigate the account takeover on one hand, but will cause a denial-of-service for the user on the other hand as he/she will be not be able to login. Therefore it is must be [implemented correctly](https://owasp.org/www-community/controls/Blocking_Brute_Force_Attacks).
3. **Not all websites/services implement account lockout** increasing the chance to for  them to be a victim if Dictionary attacks.
4. **There are much more efficient (by success rate) attacks** that can be used even when account lockout is implemented. E.g. [Credential stuffing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credential_stuffing) which realies on credentials reuse.